# GPG/SSH: Making a key a subkey after the fact

Tags: ssh, gnupg, cryptography

I'm still new to GPG, SSH, and whatnot, and I'm not sure what best practice is.

I have a USB device capable of generating and holding GPG||SSH keys without them leaving the device.  It also permits signing, with output on the local machine.

I would like a key on this device to be my master key `M`, but it's inconvenient to use this device for daily use.  Hence I would like to have another key `A`, signed by the master key, that I can keep locally and use for normal tasks.  (possibly using a Yubikey to lock it [à la](https://www.esev.com/blog/post/2015-01-pgp-ssh-key-on-yubikey-neo/)).

Since subkeys generated in what I think is the "normal way" still wouldn't leave the device, is there a standard way that I can generate a new key on `A` on my local machine and then sign it as a subkey of `M`?

**EDIT**

To clarify, the device in question is not a Yubikey, and cannot have keys transferred to it. It is more similar in function to something like a [Trezor](http://blog.trezor.io/trezor-firmware-1-3-6-20a7df6e692), where keys can only be generated on device, and cannot be copied into or out it.

The Yubikey method a good one, however I think it is vulnerable if the Yubikey is stolen. The Trezor-like one has additional layers of authentication on device, so even if stolen cannot be used. $5 wrench attacks only!

**EDIT2**
(though I guess there's also implicit trust in device manufactures)

Comment: I'm also interested in doing something similar (I'd like a Yubikey to be my physical-only ‘master key’, but use revokable subkeys for most things). Adding a bounty!

Comment: See [Transferring keys to YubiKey hardware](https://github.com/drduh/YubiKey-Guide#transfer-keys), if it answers the problem.

Answer (score 2):

An excellent resource for using YubiKey is the
[YubiKey Guide](https://github.com/drduh/YubiKey-Guide),
which describes itself as :

> This is a practical guide to using YubiKey as a SmartCard for storing
>   GPG encryption and signing keys.
>
> An authentication key can also be created for SSH and used with
>   gpg-agent.
>
> Keys stored on a smartcard like YubiKey seem more difficult to steal
>   than ones stored on disk, and are convenient for everyday use.
>
> Instructions written for Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie) using YubiKey 4 -
>   with support for 4096 bit RSA keys - in OTP+CCID mode, updated to GPG
>   version 2.2.1. Some notes are included for macOS as well.

The section of interest here is that of
[Transfer keys](https://github.com/drduh/YubiKey-Guide#transfer-keys)
which contains this warning :

> Transferring keys to YubiKey hardware is a one-way operation only, so make sure you've made a backup before proceeding.

The procedure is :

- List the keys

  ```
  gpg --edit-key $KEYID
  ```
- Select and move the signature key

  ```
  key 1
  keytocard
  ```
- Deselect, select and move the Encryption key

  ```
  key 1
  key 2
  keytocard
  ```
- Deselect, select and move the Authentication key

  ```
  key 2
  key 3
  keytocard
  ```
- Check your work

  ```
  gpg --list-secret-keys
  ```
- Export public key

  ```
  gpg --armor --export $KEYID > /mnt/public-usb-key/pubkey.txt
  ```
- Optionally, it may be uploaded to a public keyserver

  ```
    gpg --send-key $KEYID
  ```

More information can be found in the article.

Comment: this is an excellent answer, and I will be attempting to follow it in the coming weeks (once my schedule allows).  However, I cannot accept it as an answer, as the device I reference in the question is not a Yubikey, and cannot have keys transferred to it. It is more similar in function to something like a [https://blog.trezor.io/trezor-firmware-1-3-6-20a7df6e692](Trezor).  The Yubikey method a good one, however I think it is vulnerable if the Yubikey is stolen. The Trezor-like one has additional layers of authentication on device, so even if stolen cannot be used.  $5 wrench attacks only!

Comment: @PrunusPersica: There is a problem, as ELLIOTTCABLE posted a bonus specifically for the YubiKey. But I think that this procedure might work for other keys as well.

Comment: For some smartcard systems, yes.  However the one in the question does not have the `keytocard` operation as I understand it

Comment: Without knowing which one is it, I can't help.

Comment: A hardware wallet, exposed via https://github.com/romanz/trezor-agent

Comment: I don't think you can. With Trezor, all keys are generated by its seed phrase. You cannot import other keys, as they cannot be generated by this seed.

Comment: Yes, the question acknowledges this.  It asks, given that the Master key will never leave the device, is it possible to create sub-keys on the host PC, just by using the ability to sign using the Master Key

Comment: trezor-agent is supposed to enable you to do that - [link](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/46145/how-do-i-use-the-new-gpg-signing-feature-with-my-trezor). If you have problems with it, add this to your post.

Comment: @ELLIOTTCABLE: Could you please comment on this answer?

Comment: Agreed, I think that you have answered ELLIOTTCABLE's question RE Yubikey, but not mine RE off-device subkeys.  I have used trezor-agent, and it just provides an interface to gnupg.  Hence my question

Comment: You could maybe post your question for [trezor-agent](https://github.com/romanz/trezor-agent/issues). The developer is reactive. As far as I know, you can only add a trezor-based GPG key to an existing GPG identity.

Comment: Oops! Looks like I accidentally hijacked your post! Well, thanks for the answers, nonetheless …